# Creating a new has_many through instance using button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to use a Rails button_to to create a new instance in my join table.

I have 4 models (Manufacturers, batches, offers and wholesalers) - manufacturers has_many batches, batches has_many offers, and has_many wholesalers through offers. Wholesalers has_many offers and has_many batches through offers.

I'm setting up the 'new offers' view within a given batch to be a list of all wholesalers, so that the manufacturer can click a button next to an individual wholesaler which will create a new 'offer' linking that batch and the specific wholesaler.

```
<%= button_to '+', {:controller => "offers", :action => "create", :wholesaler_id => wholesaler.id}, :method=>:post  %>
```

My create method in the offers controller:

```
def create
  @offer = Offer.new(offer_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @offer.save
      format.html { redirect_to @offer, notice: 'Offer was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @offer }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @offer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

My offer_params method in the offer controller:

```
def offer_params
  params.require(:offer).permit(:batch_id, :wholesaler_id, :amount, :accepted, :ignored)
end
```

I'm getting an error when I try and click the add button -

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in OffersController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: offer
```

which refers to the offer_params method.

Since I haven't created the offer until I click the button I don't know how/where I can refer to it.

Thanks for any help - happy to post any additional code that may be useful in answering.

Full 'new' view:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="unselected">
    <h2> Wholesalers</h2>
    <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Wholesaler </th>
        <th> Add</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <% @unselected_wholesalers.each do |wholesaler| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%=wholesaler.name %></td>
            <td><%= button_to '+',
                              {:controller => "offers", :action => "create",
                               :wholesaler_id => wholesaler.id},
                              :method=>:post  %></td>
          </tr>
      <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<%= link_to 'Back', manufacturer_batches_path(@manufacturer) %>
```

Comment: could you please attach `offer` form that your send with button?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the offer form? I'm not using a form partial, I've just got the code in the new offers view - I've put the full code for this view in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the `require` statement, `offer_params` is expecting an object named `offer` containing the keys `batch_id`, `wholesaler_id`, etc. That would look like this:

```
{
    offer: {
        batch_id,
        wholesaler_id,
        amount,
        etc.
    }
}
```

But it looks like your button_to is sending this:

```
{ 
    batch_id, 
    wholesaler_id, 
    amount, 
    etc.
}
```

The simplest solution would be to remove the `require` statement, giving you an `offer_params` like this:

```
def offer_params
  params.permit(:batch_id, :wholesaler_id, :amount, :accepted, :ignored)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked, so did leaving the require in but changing the button to the following: 

   '<%= button_to '+', {:controller => "offers", :action => "create", :offer => {:batch_id => @batch.id, :wholesaler_id => wholesaler.id}}, :method=>:post  %>'